# operator += overload, why const?

Tags: c++, class, constants, operator-overloading, function-qualifier

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the meaning of a const at end of a member function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059932/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-const-at-end-of-a-member-function)

Dear all,

I was trying to overload the operator += and I was getting some error of "discard qualifiers", only by adding "const" at the end of a method, I was able to get rid of the error. Does anybody could explain me why this is needed? Below, the code.

```
class Vector{
    public:
        Vector();
        Vector(int);

        //int getLength();
        int getLength() const;
        const Vector & operator += (const Vector &);

        ~Vector();
    private:
        int m_nLength;
        int * m_pData;
};

/*int Vector::getLength(){
    return (this->m_nLength);
}*/

int Vector::getLength() const{
    return (this->m_nLength);
}

const Vector & Vector::operator += (const Vector & refVector){
    int newLength = this->getLength() + refVector.getLenth();
    ...
    ...
    return (*this);
}
```

Comment: Note that it is always a good idea to make member functions `const` if they don't need to change state.

Comment: Voted to close this as a duplicate. Basically, it is explained in [What is the meaning of a const at end of a member function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059932/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-const-at-end-of-a-member-function) (which I've now tagged as a [C++-FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq), so it will be easier to find).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `operator+=` method receives its argument as a reference-to-constant, so it is not allowed to modify the state of the object it receives.

Therefore, through a reference-to-const (or pointer-to-const) you may only:

- read the accessible fields in that object (not write),
- **call only the methods with the `const` qualifier** (which indicates that this method is guaranteed not to modify the internal state of the object),
- read or write accessible fields declared as `mutable` (which is very seldomly used and not relevant here).

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

`+=` modifies its left-hand argument, which is `*this` when you overload it for a class. Therefore, you can't make that argument `const`. Instead, use

```
Vector &Vector::operator+=(const Vector &refVector);
```

That being said, because its right-hand argument has to be `const` (by definition), you can't call a non-`const` member function on the right-hand argument (`refVector`).

Comment: But that's not why `getLength` has to be a const method. It's `refVector.getLength` that's the problem.

Comment: @Peter Milley, I was getting to that.

Comment: OK, thanks! BTW, if I should remove the first occurrence of "const" so as to have: Vector &Vector::operator+=(const Vector &refVector);
why, I saw in some cases a const parameter when overloading the "operator =", if we need to modify the left-hand argument, e.g.: const Vector &Vector::operator =(const Vector & right)

Comment: AFAICT, that can't be correct, unless maybe one wants to prevent `x = y = z;` from working.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling `getLength` on `refVector`, which is a `const Vector &`. You can only call `const` methods on a `const` reference.

Answer (score 1):

`operator+=` takes a const reference to `refVector`; you're only allowed to call const methods on const references, so `getLength()` has to be const.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling it like this `refVector.getLength()`, and `refVector` is declared `const Vector & refVector`, so `getLength` has to be declared as ok to call on a `const`.

Answer (score 0):

Your implementation of `operator+=` takes a `const Vector&` onto which you call the method `getLength()`.

However, you can't call `getLength()` on a `const` object if the object (or a reference to it) is `const`.

That's why you add to add `const` after `getLength()` declaration, so as to say that it is ok to call it even on `const` objects.

Answer (score 0):

`refVector` is a `const Vector&`, so it can only call `const` member functions from `Vector`.

The `const` at the end of the method signifies that the method will not modify the internal state of `this`, and allows the method to be called be `const` objects.

Answer (score 0):

In `operator+=`, `refVector` is a `const` parameter. This means that the function guarantees not to alter it, and any attempt to do so won't compile.

Adding the `const` keyword after a function's declaration is a guarantee that that function won't alter its receiver. In other words `int getLength();` could, theoretically, alter `refVector` in `refVector.getLength();`. `int getLength() const;` is guaranteed not to. So the first won't compile, but the second will.