# return a const reference to an object

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, constants

I have conflict in below codes.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class TestApp {
public:

    TestApp(int _x = 9) {
        cout << "default constructor\n";
    }

    TestApp(const TestApp &app) {
        cout << "Copy constructor\n";
    }

    ~TestApp() {
        cout << "destructor\n";
    }

    void setX(int _x) {
    }

    const TestApp &operator=(TestApp &obj) {
        cout << "= operator\n";
        return *this;
    }

    void setX(int _x) {
        cout << "Inside setX\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    TestApp app1;
    TestApp app2;
    TestApp app3;
    (app1 = app2) = app3; // 1
    app1 = app2 = app3; // 2
    app1.setX(3)
    return 0;
}
```

I got this error: for line 1 `main.cpp:38: error: passing ‘const TestApp’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘const TestApp& TestApp::operator=(TestApp&)’ discards qualifiers`
However I can use `app1.setX(3);`

```
main.cpp:38: error: no match for ‘operator=’ in ‘app1 = app2.TestApp::operator=(((TestApp&)(& app3)))’
main.cpp:28: note: candidates are: const TestApp& TestApp::operator=(TestApp&)
```

and to make it working I should make `operator=` like:

```
TestApp &operator=(const TestApp &obj) {
        cout << "= operator\n";
        return *this;
} // works for 1

TestApp &operator=(TestApp &obj) {
        cout << "= operator\n";
        return *this;
} // works for 2
```

why if I remove `const` keyword it works? and after line 1 `app1` object is not constant.

Comment: And solution 1 won´t work for line 2?

Comment: yup I know, so I put comment to show for which line the code will work.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Please, read a good introduction. `const` applies to variables, and is a promise to the compiler. See e.g http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059932/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-const-at-end-of-a-member-function/4059936#4059936 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c/2139254#2139254

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not assign constant objects. For example consider this simple code

```
const int x = 10;
x = 20;
```

The compiler will issue an error for the second statement because x is a constant object and may not be assigned.

The same is valid for statement

```
(app1 = app2) = app3;
```

here expression `(app1 = app2)` returns constant reference that may not be assigned,

A constant reference does not mean that the object itself that it refers to is constant. Consider the following example

```
int x = 10;
const int &rx = x;

x = 20;
rx = 30;
```

Though rx is defined as constant reference you may change the object x itself. You may not use the reference to assign object x, so the compiler will issue an error for the last statement.

We use constant references very often in parameter declarations of functions that to prevent changing of objects they refer to inside the functions. For example

```
void f( const int &x ) 
{
   x = 20;  // compilation error
}

int x = 10;

f( x );
```

So defining a constant reference to a non-constant object does not makes the object itself constant. It only prevents to change the object using this reference.

And you need to define only one copy assignment operator

```
TestApp &operator=(const TestApp &obj) {
        cout << "= operator\n";
        return *this;
} // works for 1
```

There is no any need to define the copy assignment operator as

```
TestApp &operator=(TestApp &obj) {
        cout << "= operator\n";
        return *this;
} // works for 2
```

if you are not going to change the right operand. So it is better to define it as a constant reference `const TestApp &obj`

Of course you may have these two operators together but there is no any sense to have the second operator.

On the other hand you may not have only the second operator. In this case you will be unable to use constant objects that assign them to other objects.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to provide an assignment operator is to declare it as follows:

```
TestApp &operator=(const TestApp &obj) {
    cout << "= operator\n";
    return *this;
}
```

Note that there is only one `const` in front of the right hand side operand, the operator itself and its return value are not declared `const`.

It is wrong to declare the operator `const` because the assignment operator is *meant* to modify the `this` object.

And it unnecessarily constrains the use of the operator to return a `const` reference, because the caller already provided you with a non-`const` reference. Consequently, the caller already has non-`const` access to the object, so returning a `const` reference unnecessarily stops him from reusing the return value in a non-`const` context

This is what happens when you do the double assignment `app1 = app2 = app3;`: It is evaluated as `app1 = (app2 = app3);`, so the return value of one assignment is passed as the right hand side parameter to the next assignment. The non-`const` reference returned by the first assignment can implicitly be converted to a `const` reference, so this works fine.

If your compiler complains about your line 2 with the declaration given above, then your compiler is to blame. I have checked the following code with gcc 4.7.2, and it works fine:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo() {};
        Foo(const Foo& other) {}
        Foo& operator=(const Foo& other) { return *this; }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo1, foo2, foo3;
    (foo1 = foo2) = foo3;
    foo1 = foo2 = foo3;
}
```