# Overload + operator for integer array, What's difference between two function const and without const at right?

Tags: c++, arrays, integer, constants

This is class of array to access the array of IntegerSet.
You need access to the pointer **ptr** of IntegerSet **GetPtr()**;

You need access to the **capacity** of IntegerSet **GetCapacity()**;

**GetPtr() const** to const IntegerSet class.

```
class IntegerSet
{
 private:
    int capacity;
    int nelements;
    int * ptr;
public :
IntegerSet(int  size);
~IntegerSet();
int * GetPtr() const {return ptr;};
int Getcapacity() const {return capacity;};
IntegerSet &  operator =(const IntegerSet & rhs1);
friend IntegerSet  operator +(const IntegerSet & rhs1,const IntegerSet & rhs2);
};

IntegerSet::IntegerSet(int  size)
{
ptr=null;
capacity = size;
ptr = new int [capacity];
if(ptr==null) cout << "error allocation"<< endl;

}
~IntegerSet()
{
if (ptr) delete ptr;
}
IntegerSet & IntegerSet::operator =(const IntegerSet & rhs1)
{
int capacity_=rhs1.Getcapacity();
int *rptr1=rhs1.GetPtr();
for (int i=0;i<capacity_;i++)
{
ptr[i]=rptr1[i]; // ptr is pointer of class IntegerSet 
}
return *this;
}
 //this function friend of class IntegerSet is extern ..
IntegerSet  operator +(const IntegerSet & rhs1,const int& rhs2)
{
int capacity_=rhs1.Getcapacity();
IntegerSet  temp(capacity_);
int *rptr1=rhs1.GetPtr();
int *tptr=temp.GetPtr();
for (int i=0;i<capacity_;i++)
{
tptr[i]=rptr1[i]+rhs2;
}
return temp;
}
```

what's difference between two function **int * GetPtr() const** and **int * GetPtr();** ?

Comment: One is in the code. The other is not.

Comment: If the `IntegerSet` itself is `const`, then `GetPtr() const` is usable, wheras `GetPtr()` is not.  The definitions are probably otherwise identical

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the meaning of a const at end of a member function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059932/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-const-at-end-of-a-member-function)

Comment: Do you really need to post all that code to ask that question?

Comment: i see, i understand . const IntegerSet & rhs1 is const class