# Error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*'

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to create a simple 3x3 matrix class and be able to access its contents by the subscript operator. Here's the code:

```
// Matrix.h
class Matrix {
private:
    int matrix[3][3];
public:
    int* operator[](const int index) const;
};

// Matrix.cpp
int* Matrix::operator[](const int index) const {
    return this->matrix[index];
}
```

I want to be able to access the elements of the array no matter whether the Matrix's object is const or non-const. But I get the following error from the compiler:

error: invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*' [-fpermissive]

I did some research and I have a hypothesis: maybe, because I have declared this member function as a const function, inside its definition the compiler treats (it masks) all of the the object's non-mutable members as const members, so that would be the reason the compiler says it's an invalid conversion from 'const int*' to 'int*'. **My question: Is this hypothesis correct? And if it's not, why does that happens?** I think it makes sense and would be a great way of ensuring the const-ness of the 'const Matrix *this' object.

**Compiler Info:** gcc 5.3.0 downloaded from equation.com

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4059932/what-is-the-meaning-of-a-const-at-end-of-a-member-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are absolutely right about the reason why you get the error: inside a member function marked `const` the compiler implicitly treats all data members of the class as if they were declared with a `const` qualifier.

The fix is really straightforward - you can override the same operator twice, providing a `const` and a non-`const` versions:

```
class Matrix {
private:
    int matrix[3][3];
public:
    const int* operator[](const int index) const;
    int* operator[](const int index);
};

// Matrix.cpp
const int* Matrix::operator[](const int index) const {
    return this->matrix[index];
}
int* Matrix::operator[](const int index) {
    return this->matrix[index];
}
```

The compiler will figure out which overload to call based on the context. It will call `const` version if the `Matrix` itself is `const`, and the non-`const` version otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

When you declare a class method (and operator is a class method) `const`, that means you can only call `const` methods on your class's fields and return only `const` pointers or references to class fields. In order to compile, you need to make up your mind to have either:

```
const int* Matrix::operator[](const int index) const { return this->matrix[index]; }
```

or

```
int* Matrix::operator[](const int index) { return this->matrix[index]; }
```

or both.

Comment: Didn't know about the return limitation in const functions, thanks! But I was expecting some answer about the compiler's behavior. And as dasblinkenlight said I can have both functions!
=D

Answer (score 2):

```
int* Matrix::operator[](const int index) const {
    return this->matrix[index]; }
```

Here you say you don't modify the state of your object by specifying function as  `const`.

But you are returning a pointer to your instance variable - and through that pointer it is possible to change value of the instance variable of your class (and thus the state).

So you can create a non const version of that operator to avoid that issue.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are return a `pointer` from a `const member function` (or `operator`).

`const member function` and `operator` should not change any `non-mutable` member neither return `pointers` that can change them later.

Make your operator return const pointer rather than pointer.

```
class Matrix {
private:
    int matrix[3][3];
public:
    int const* operator[](const int index) const;
};

// Matrix.cpp
int const* Matrix::operator[](const int index) const {
    return this->matrix[index];
}
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/7ofw)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
int* Matrix::operator[](const int index) const
```

to this

```
const int* Matrix::operator[](const int index) const
```

You cannot return mutable pointer to data member from const function.

Or you may create two versions of operator: const and non const:

```
const int* Matrix::operator[](const int index) const;
int* Matrix::operator[](const int index);
```

PS. And anyway it's a very bad practice to return pointer or reference to internal class members.

Comment: I want to be able to access the matrix member as if it was a 2-dimensional array (eg: Matrix m; m[2][1] = 7.5;) and also be able to do other matrix operations using operator overloading (eg: Matrix m1, m2; m1 += m2; m2 *= m1). So that's why I am using an class, and the reason why the 'int matrix[3][3]' member is private is just for hiding the implementation. I guess there's no other way of using the object like m[2][1] (subscript operator twice) without returning a pointer, and actually I see no problem in doing that. =)

Answer (score 0):

hope this helps:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Matrix
{
private:
    int matrix[3][3];
public:
    const int* operator[](const int index) const;
    Matrix(int* value); // need an initializer though :)
};

const int* Matrix::operator[](const int index) const
{
    return this->matrix[index];
}

Matrix::Matrix(int* value)
{
    for(int i=0; i<3;i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            matrix[i][j]= *value;
            value++;
        }
    }
}

int main( void )
{
    int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    Matrix C(arr);

    const int *c;
    c = C[0];

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cout << *c << ends;
        c++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```